# Memory issue in db-access IOS ORM on commit and Fetch

Tags: ios, iphone, orm, dbaccess

i am using db-access `ORM` in my one iOS project. I am facing memory issue while using it in my project my app scenario is, I need to download data from server to the local db in pages form in background threads in my app.

Steps I am doing is fetch a page of 30 records from server,
Then in loop check the record exist in db by using

```
firstMatchOf:@"product_uuid" withValue:productUuid
```

method.

Then if it does not return then create object and commit using following chunk of code

```
productObj = [Products new];
productObj.product_name=name;
productObj.product_uuid=productUuid;
BOOL success=[productObj commit];
```

there are many records, and I can see in profiler that fetch function and commit function retaining too much memory and does not release the memory. So for instance I downloaded 40 pages of 30 records the app memory usage become 100MB and it is increasing with increasing of records.
Can you please help my in memory management issue or if I am doing anything wrong please assist me.

You help will be highly appreciated.

Here is snapshot of Instruments memory Allocation
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dvftqq&s=8#.VKVdOaaZL0g

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the objects coming out of DBAccess are being retained somehow.

There was a known bug in the current build when performing queries within event blocks, but you make no mention of using that part of the framework so we will discount it for now.

I have emailed you a version of DBAccess with that fault fixed anyhow, just in case that is in any way related.

Part of our automated testing involves loops of queries and then inserts, could you separate this scenario from all the other code to replicate it within an autorelease pool?